# l1 regularized logistic regression with the response -1 or 1, not 0, 1

Tags: r, optimization, logistic-regression, lasso-regression

I want to fit the model using l1 regularized logistic regression.
The response is -1, or 1, instead of 0 or 1.

I am trying to reproduce the simulation of High-dimensional Ising model selection using ℓ1-regularized logistic regression, Ravikumar et al (2010).

I generated the data from the ising model having the response as -1 or 1.
For generating data, I modified isingibbs function in R. (from 0 or 1 to -1 or 1).

Next, the authors use l1_logreg function in C. This function is used for the binary response, -1 or 1.
However, I do not know C, so I found the R function, glmnet, for fitting the model.
I wonder whether I can use the glmnet function for the response having -1, or 1.
Or could you please let me know another R function to use for -1 or 1 response?

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you just convert the -1 to 0?

Comment: In the paper, they use the response -1, 1. I think that it is required for what they did in the paper.

Comment: Well it is completely arbitrary. -1 and 1 just represent a binary yes or no. They aren't numeric.

Comment: But yes you can use glmnet with -1,1. just plug it in as usual.

Comment: I think that the value of the conditional distribution are different. It does not affect?

Comment: @Quality the notion of -1 and 1 though considered arbitrary, do impact the model estimation. Note that they are coded as numeric 0 and 1 or numeric -1 and 1. eg you cannot use 0,1 coding when doing svm.

Comment: @onyambu it impacts the interpretation of the coefficients, but glmnet won't have a problem with -1,1. Does the conditional distribution not remain the same? And does not glmnet treat the Y as factors?

Comment: @Quality I generated data as -1, 1, and then fit using glmnet. And then, I converted -1 to 0, and fit using glmnet again. Then, the estimated coefficients are different.

Comment: The coefficients will be different. How one level relates to the baselines remains the same. If you can fit to -1,1, isn't that what you were asking how to do?

Comment: @Quality its not a matter of interpretation. There will be no problem formulation and definition if we use 0 and 1 in svm for example. Though we know that -1 and 1 are just two classes, the classes must be coded as such. otherwise the problem breaks

Comment: @onyambu Sure, but he is not doing svm. Glmnet can handle -1,1 in logistic regression which is what he is asking. All he has to do is plug it Y to glmnet.

Comment: @Quality I dont know much about glmnet. I am just putting across the notion that the problem formulation/definition will determine whether to use -1,1 or 0,1

Comment: In this case it wont matter. But you are right that if he wants to recreate the exact numbers he saw in the paper, then he can keep it as -1,1 instead of 0,1 or factor No/yes

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.